# Is it a good practice to set route to a model's action using the name of a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my design, a `user` has a `membership_card` and user can top up credits in the card.
The method `topup` is used to recharge the card.

I think `topup` should be inside `MembershipCardController`, but I want to make my URL look more readable, so here is what I did:

```
post 'users/:id/topup' => "membership_cards#topup", as: "user_topup"
```

Is this a good practice to do?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd create the `topup` resource inside the `users` resource and do the same with `pay` I think it would also make your tests more readable and easier to create.

Comment: My only concern is that the `topup` action is more related to the `membership_card` rather than `user`. Will it make my code not SOLID enough if I put `topup` in `user`?